# How to change the field to a search icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

How to change the field to icon, for mobile devices?
Like in the example below:

[image: Example image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="divLogo input-group" style="float: right;">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <!--How change to icon?-->
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier , 
I tried to change to the resize icon via css, but it didn't work. And I used some similar examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can do the same result with media queries by depending on the different screen resolution it will display or not. for this example i took the resolution of 1000px and 700px, obviusly you can take a font awesome icon instead of my ugly button ! ;)

```
<body>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="divLogo input-group" style="float: right;">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <!--How change to icon?-->
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the css:

```
.input-group-btn {
  display: block;
}

.icon-new {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 400px) {
  .input-group-btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .form-control {
    display: none;
  }

  .icon-new {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
```

and another element will show up, the you can make a small script with Js using addEventListener to disable the display 'none' for the input and shape up with css style for width.